# What is the best hash function for uint64_t keys ranging from 0 to its max value?

Tags: c++, algorithm, hashtable, hash

Assuming that we have a set of elements and want to store them in a hash map (for example `std::unordered_set`), and each element has a key of type `uint64_t` whose value can vary from 0 to its maximum possible value, is it the best choice to use trivial hash function, where a hash value of a key is the key itself? Does it depend on container in use (i.e. Google's sparse hash vs `std::unordered_map` from STL)? The probability of appearance of key values is unknown.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If all you have to hash is a uint64_t of any possible value with unknown probabilities, and your output must be a uint64_t, then you don't gain any advantage by changing the value.  Just use the key itself.

If you knew something about the distribution of your values or your values were restricted to a smaller range (which is really the same thing as knowing about the distribution), then it could be beneficial to apply a transformation to the key, but this depends on the implementation of the container.  You would only benefit by reducing collisions when the table transforms a hash into a bucket index, but that depends both on the table's algorithm and the current/average state of the table (how often each bucket is used).

Comment: Thanks, Thomas. Can I extend my question? I am just trying to come up with an idea. Say, uint64_t is actually 8 ASCII characters (A-Za-z0-9). But we treat it as uint64_t. Can we do something smarter with that?

Comment: @Vlad Lazarenko: Using all 8 bytes that way will be fairly distributed, and that's generally the case for which generic hash tables are tuned, so probably not.  Look at how the specific container you're using is tuned, but this isn't more than a small micro-optimization.

Comment: @Vlad: if you want bit-perfect randomness in your hash value, you want to remove the constant parts (e.g. the most-significant bit may be 0 in every character), pack the variable bits together, then consider whether any particular values, combinations or permutations in the A-Za-z0-9 set are more frequent than others. If they're equally likely, then you've got 62 values in that set and can combine the 8 characters ala a + 62 * b + 62 * 62 * c etc (assuming you normalise a, b, c into the range 0..61).  (All that may waste more time than a few extra collisions.)

Comment: @Tony: "Compacting" the key shouldn't make a significant difference.  Modifying the key so the hash table gets fewer collisions when it transforms it into a bucket index is what matters, but this depends on the underlying implementation and the current load (how many buckets are in use).

Comment: @Thomas: a great hash function works well with a variety of hash table implementations.  Consider the uncompacted hash with a very simple but common hash table implementation, currently having 256 buckets, that simply `%`-ed an uncompacted hash value into the # buckets: only the 62 hash buckets associated with the A-Za-z0-9 characters would be used, resulting in far more collisions.  By compacting, all the lower bits (which are most important) vary far more.

Comment: If you know the upper bound for the size of the set you could try modulus by that value.

Comment: @Tony: A generic hash function works well with a variety of hash tables and optimally with none.  If you just want really good performance, a BST (a la std::map) is almost always enough.

Comment: @Thomas: "optimally with none"... sorry, but must disagree: there's a large proportion of hash table uses where it's optimal to have "random but reproducable" mappings onto the buckets.  A hash function that achieves effectively random and independent values in every bit of the hash value satisfies this optimally for almost any hash table design.  You can only beat this when some property of the input keys can be actively exploited to provide better-than-random placement.  I'll leave the readers to judge/measure when hashing outperforms binary trees ;-P.

Comment: @Tony: Sorry, I meant when the hash function wasn't trivial and actually had some information to use.  The degenerate case of identity hash cannot, of course, be improved, but neither can it exploit any implementation property of the table.  FWIW, packing the values as you commented on earlier defeats "effectively random and independent values in every bit of the hash".

Comment: Well, we agree then :-).  Re "effectively random" and packing - my statement was prefixed with "If [the 62 values] are equally likely".  In that case, the packing achieved effectively random and independent values in every bit of a smaller-width hash value: we have almost 6 random bits in each of 8 characters, so the lower ~48 bits of the resultant key are "perfect" quality: it's no longer a 64-bit hash value.  As illustrated with the 256-bucket example above, consolidating the randomness across each of the lower-significance bits is the (at least theoretical) goal.

Answer (score 13):

I would suggest a good 64-bit mixer of which there are many to choose from. The finalizer from MurmerHash3 is fairly quick and does a reasonable job in just five lines of code:

```
key ^= key >> 33;
key *= 0xff51afd7ed558ccd;
key ^= key >> 33;
key *= 0xc4ceb9fe1a85ec53;
key ^= key >> 33;
```

Numerical Recipes, 3rd Edition, recommends this:

```
public static UInt64 Next( UInt64 u )
  {
  UInt64 v = u * 3935559000370003845 + 2691343689449507681;

  v ^= v >> 21;
  v ^= v << 37;
  v ^= v >>  4;

  v *= 4768777513237032717;

  v ^= v << 20;
  v ^= v >> 41;
  v ^= v <<  5;

  return v;
  }
```

Answer (score -2):

HashMaps are very useful in giving you fast access to data. The complexity of hash operations are `O(1)` which are very fast compared to other well-known structures such as double linked lists, linked lists or trees.

To use `uint64_t` as a key for the hash, you can use hash containers such as [GHASHLISH](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Hash-Tables.html)

The `GLIB` library is thread-safe and used by multiple open source projects. It does not support `uint64_t` as a key natively, so you have to provide your own hash_function.

As an example, you can use [FNV hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fowler%E2%80%93Noll%E2%80%93Vo_hash_function)

Here's a quick example of how to hash `uint64` to `uint32` using FNV:

```
#define FNV_offset_basis 2166136261
#define FNV_prime        16777619
guint c_uint64_t_hash(gpointer data)
{
  uint8_t* v =(uint8_t*)data;
  guint hash = FNV_offset_basis;
  for(int i=0;i<8;i++)
  {
    hash = hash ^ v[i];
    hash = hash * FNV_prime;
  }
return hash;
}
```