# hashing a small number to a random looking 64 bit integer

Tags: algorithm, random, hash

I am looking for a hash-function which operates on a small integer (say in the range 0...1000) and outputs a 64 bit int.

The result-set should look like a random distribution of 64 bit ints: a uniform distribution with no linear correlation between the results.

I was hoping for a function that only takes a few CPU-cycles to execute. (the code will be in C++).

I considered multiplying the input by a big prime number and taking the modulo 2**64 (something like a linear congruent generator), but there are obvious dependencies between the outputs (in the lower bits).

Googling did not show up anything, but I am probably using wrong search terms.

Does such a function exist?

---

Some Background-info:

I want to avoid using a big persistent table with pseudo random numbers in an algorithm, and calculate random-looking numbers on the fly.

Security is not an issue.

Comment: Have you seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5085915/what-is-the-best-hash-function-for-uint64-t-keys-ranging-from-0-to-its-max-value Both answers are very interesting!

Comment: @kol, I missed this before, it looks very interesting indeed. I will comment tomorrow.

Comment: If your numbers are between 0 and 1000, a precomputed table won't be 'big' - it'll consume about 8k of memory. It's also the fastest possible algorithm. Is this really a problem?

Comment: 8k could be a lot of memory (at least a lot of cache; if the lookup misses cache, then the MurmurHash3 finalizer is faster on current commodity hardware), but it sounds as though the OP is doing Zobrist hashing, so I'm not buying it either.

Comment: @per I posed the question more generally, but I am indeed trying to implement Zobrist hashing.I thought this question would have more uses, so I am flabbergasted that you figured this out. I was inspired by a post from Linus Torvalds about lookup-tables: [lookup-tables](http://yarchive.net/comp/linux/lookup_tables.html). So, I would like to give it a try.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I tested the 64-bit finalizer of MurmurHash3 (suggested by @aix and [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5085915/what-is-the-best-hash-function-for-uint64-t-keys-ranging-from-0-to-its-max-value)). This gives zero if the input is zero, so I increased the input parameter by 1 first:

```
typedef unsigned long long uint64;

inline uint64 fasthash(uint64 i)
{
  i += 1ULL;
  i ^= i >> 33ULL;
  i *= 0xff51afd7ed558ccdULL;
  i ^= i >> 33ULL;
  i *= 0xc4ceb9fe1a85ec53ULL;
  i ^= i >> 33ULL;
  return i;
}
```

Here the input argument `i` is a small integer, for example an element of `{0, 1, ..., 1000}`. The output looks random:

```
i       fasthash(i) decimal:    fasthash(i) hex:
0       12994781566227106604    0xB456BCFC34C2CB2C
1       4233148493373801447     0x3ABF2A20650683E7
2       815575690806614222      0x0B5181C509F8D8CE
3       5156626420896634997     0x47900468A8F01875
...     ...                     ...
```

There is no linear correlation between subsequent elements of the series:

[image: fasthash autocorrelation]

The range of both axes is `0..2^64-1`

Answer (score 2):

Why not use an existing hash function, such as [MurmurHash3](http://code.google.com/p/smhasher/) with a 64-bit finalizer? According to the author, the function takes tens of CPU cycles per key on current Intel hardware.

Comment: My input is very short, so the intermix step is probably not needed. It will take me some time to figure out if the finalizer can be used stand-alone.

Comment: +1 for suggesting MurmurHash3. I tested its finalizer in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Given: input i in the range of 0 to 1,000.

const MaxInt which is the maximum value that cna be contained in a 64 bit int. (you did not say if it is signed or unsigned; 2^64 = 18446744073709551616 )

and a function rand() that returns a value between 0 and 1 (most languages have such a function)

compute hashvalue = i * rand() * ( MaxInt / 1000 )

Comment: I would like unsigned 64 bit integers. I should have mentioned that I expect reproducible results, so rand() cannot be used.

Comment: if you seed rand() using srand() with the same value, it will produce the same numbers, so @JonnyBoats is correct.  see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/srand/

Comment: By reproducible results do you mean that for each of 1,000 possible input values you get one of 1,000 possible hash values? That requirement confilcts with "The result-set should look like a random distribution of 64 bit ints"

Comment: I think the OP means that he wants the hashes of the 1000 input values to be distributed over the 64-bit integer space.  He also expects that f(x) is deterministic.  So, as I said, as long as he seeds rand() with a constant value, this fits his criteria.

Answer (score 1):

1,000 * 1,000 = 1,000,000.  That fits well within an Int32.

Subtract the low bound of your range, from the number.
Square it, and use it as a direct subscript into some sort of bitmap.

Comment: This would be too easy :) He said: "I want to avoid using a big persistent table with pseudo random numbers"

Comment: I hadn't considered 125k to be big.  My Bad :)