# Hash a small integer value to a big 16 digit unique number

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, hash

I've a situation to create a 16 digit number from another integer. It should be like a credit card number. So what is our scenario is if that users ID is 1 or 2, that should be hashed to a 16 digit string (Numeric). So that 16 digit should be unique for 1
I tried to .NET builtin functions like generate hash etc.

That doesn't helped me for a perfect solution

Comment: possible duplicate of [hashing a small number to a random looking 64 bit integer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8509180/hashing-a-small-number-to-a-random-looking-64-bit-integer)

Comment: Yes, you're right, I am, I've deleted my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how many users you expect, but this code produces 16 digit integers and using the numbers from 1 to 100 there were no repeats:

```
Imports System.Security.Cryptography

    Dim sha As New SHA1CryptoServiceProvider()
    Dim IntList As New List(Of ULong)
    For I = 1 To 100000
        'Need a byte array for the ComputeHash method
        Dim data() As Byte = BitConverter.GetBytes(I)
        If BitConverter.IsLittleEndian Then Array.Reverse(data)
        'Store the 160 bit hash in a byte array
        Dim result As Byte() = sha.ComputeHash(data)
        'Bitconverter's result can be too long, so by taking the first 16 digits _
         of the results that are too long, and padding the rest to the right with _
        0's we end up with unique 16 digit integers
        Dim HashInt As ULong = ULong.Parse(BitConverter.ToUInt64(result, 0).ToString.PadRight(16, "0"c).Substring(0, 16))
        'Using a list to hold the hash's is just to confirm that each one is unique. _
        for the your purposes I would suggest a dictionary(of integer, ulong)
        If Not IntList.Contains(HashInt) Then
            IntList.Add(HashInt)
        End If
    Next
```

UPDATE: modified the code to show that it will produce 100000 unique hash's.  IntList.Count = 100000.

For results that end up being less than 16 digits, I padded the end with 0's.  This is just convenient.  By putting the BitConverter.ToUInt64 result into a string you can insert the 0's anywhere you like.

Comment: The number of users will be more than 50K. So am afraid a chance of a duplicate in this substring method from hash.

Comment: 50,000 will still all be unique.  I updated my code to show that even 100000 will be unique.  The Count property of intlist equals 100000 when the loop is finished

Comment: It worked well for 100000 users and since its checking unique values in the list I hope no chance of duplicates. Hope it will work smoothly for more than 100K.

Comment: If necessary and you've got the time to test for more, just use a bigger limit in the for loop and compare the size of IntList. Hope this is enough for you mark this answered.  thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use this:

```
string SixteenDigitHash(int value)
{
   var rnd = new Random(value);
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(16);
   sb.Append(rnd.Next(1,10)); // first digit 1..9
   for (int i=1; i<16; i++)
   {
     sb.Append(rnd.Next(0,10)); // other digits 0..9
   }

   return sb.ToString();
}
```

It uses `Random` to generate (pseudo) random numbers, but uses the value-to-hash as seed so it always generates the same sequence for a given value and different sequences for different values.

One problem: the sequence is not guaranteed to be the same for different versions of the framework. Maybe you should use your own implementation of that Random class so that you *know* that the sequence is stable.

Comment: Seems to be nice one.. Working fine. But I didnt understand how its always returning the same value even when using random

Comment: @sforsandeep - That's because Random isn't really random: it uses plain mathematical operations to arrive at a seemingly random sequence. Usually the seed (start value) is the current time, so you always get a new sequence, but now I specify the seed.