# Collisions when using stdext::hash_set/hash_map with object pointers

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, pointers, hashmap, hashset

I'm currently using MS VC++ 2008 with its supplied standard library with extensions.
I want to use hashed containers for fast insert/delete/lookup of objects. So I thought this should work just nice:

```
stdext::hash_set<MyOjbectClass*>
```

What I discovered is that collisions are very high with default hash function (which I assume just uses the pointer value).

When I run the following code in debugger:

```
stdext::hash_set<void*> hs;
for (int i=0; i<30; i++)
{
    hs.insert(new std::string());
}
```

I see that ALL items were placed in the same bucket! (facepalm)
Though all pointers are unique. So I can forget about O(1).

So, what is the right way to make it work efficiently?

Provide a custom hash function? Which is good with such pointers?

Note: I need to use hash_map/hash_set. Please don't offer to use unordered_map/set or boost, etc.

Answer (score 0):

After searching a little, I found few hashes. The following resources were helpful:

2 functions found here: [What is the best hash function for uint64_t keys ranging from 0 to its max value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5085915/what-is-the-best-hash-function-for-uint64-t-keys-ranging-from-0-to-its-max-value?rq=1)

and 1 function here: http://naml.us/blog/2012/03

After some testing the MurmurHash3 showed best results for me. It has best performance. The standard deviation of bucket distribution is almost the same for all 3 hash functions, and it is much better than in case of using standard hash function.